# Menus in backend

Tags: ee2

After having a 3rd party company upgrade us to 2.10.1, we have a couple nagging issues. A couple of the nav menus in the backend have items that are underscored descriptions, instead of menu items. Where do I fix that?

[image: I want to change nav_template_route_manager]

Same thing for the label for the user and password, when the system logs me out, its something like password_label, instead of Enter Password.

Tried to Google this but only got results for front end UX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because you are missing language files or they are corrupt. That language variable lives here:

```
/your_web_root/system/expressionengine/language/english/cp_lang.php
```

That file has an array of language variables. Look for that one, if it's missing, the file is probably corrupt and you should get a new copy of that entire directory and re-upload it. Before you do, though, **back up that folder**. Always back-up before modifying core files and directories, although those are just language files so it's not likely you will crash your site.

**Edit**

Oh, also, why are **you** fixing this? Your 3rd party company must be really awful if they aren't willing to look into this, especially since this is clearly their mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Easy fix. Would there have been a reason for the upgrade not to include ALL files that came with the 2.10.1 upgrade? It looks like it was the english directory from 2013, I'm guessing when we upgraded to 2.6. As for the 3rd party company...we were paying them hourly and there were more major issues that I wanted to have them work on, as we were quite far behind in our upgrades, which caused several front end problems.

Comment: Something stupid like your third party having a corrupt copy; or their FTP agent bailed at that folder and they just went `DERP YAY IT'S FINISHED UPLOADING`. Keep all of this in mind if you start experiencing other weird behavior... what else didn't get upgraded properly?